# Array element adding using if condtion

Tags: php, arrays

I want get an array of errors using if condition

my code is below

```
$errors = array();
if(empty($name))
  $errors[] = 'Name required';
elseif(empty($usernmae))
  $errors[] ='Username required';
```

final output i expect

```
$errors = array([0]=>'Name Required',[1]=>'username required');
```

but it returns only one array element

```
 $errors = array([0]=>'Name Required');
```

anyone know

Comment: For now - _God only knows_ (what did you mean by "but it returns only one array element"). So, show the code about - how did you discover that there's only one element

Comment: There is a typo in the username variable: $usernmae

Comment: Don't use `elseif`. Use `if(empty($name)) $errors[] = "Name required"; if(empty($username)) $errors[] = "Username required";`

Comment: PLease read the docs about `elseif`. Then replace `elseif` by `if`.

Comment: The code in both `if` block and `elseif` blocks *both* would **never** get executed. That's the point of `if`, `else` and `elseif` control structures.

Answer (score 4):

```
elseif(empty($usernmae))
```

It will only do this as an `else`, so you won't ever have both errors returned.

If you want both, you need to do it as two if's:

```
if(empty($name))
  $errors[] = 'Name required';
if(empty($usernmae))
  $errors[] ='Username required';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only `if` instead of `else if`

```
$errors = array();
if(empty($name))
 $errors[] = 'Name required';
if(empty($username))
 $errors[] ='Username required';
```